# Problem passing application assets to deploy code to ElasticBeanstalk with CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Following this walkthrough of the Pipeline setup:
https://www.buildon.aws/tutorials/deploy-webapp-eb-cdk
(naturally open to alternatives, advise and better practices)

I have two stacks which set up the infra:

1. CodePipeline
2. ElasticBeanstalk (where the problem seems to be)

My file structure (when Pipeline construct pulls it down) is: 
  root *(where my app's package.json is)* 
     -- infra *(where all of cdk is)* 
         -- lib (where Asset module seems to run from) 
     -- others

**Problem I'm facing is:** 
when I try to call the Asset module (as suggested in the tutorial above), it does not allow me to get to where the folder pulled down by the pipeline construct is. As Assets requires to be given a folder as a parameter, I can't give it everything in current. And if I try try to go back a folder and then reference the directory I was just in, it does not complete the synth.

Snippet example:
*"git_repo_name" translates to where the Pipeline construct should be pulling to*

```
const AddressbookApiZipArchive = new Asset(this, `${apiName}Zip`, {
  path: `${__dirname}/../../../git_repo_name`
});
```

**Error observed when I try to set the path outside of the root directory:**

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'xxx\root\infra\cdk.out\asset.fed10dfa61a9f62ac623f44df32746d8e161d2d427b375326095b59f852460ac\cdk.out\asset.fed10dfa61a9f62ac623f44df32746d8e161d2d427b375326095b59f852460ac\cdk.out\asset.fed10dfa61a9f62ac623f44df32746d8e161d2d427b375326095b59f852460ac\cdk.out\[... repeating pattern]
```